# Tango with django chapter 19 -- Adding Inline Category Suggestions

Tags: python, django

I was stuck with chapter 19 in *Tango With Django*. And i just try to follow the 'Adding Inline Category Suggestions' code shown in the book. But when i input *python* and nothing happened.

Here's my code

base.html

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li class="nav-header">Find a Category</li>
    <form>
    <label></label>
    <li><input class="search-query span10" type="text" name="suggestion" value="" id="suggestion" /></li>
    </form>
</ul>

    <div id="cats">
    </div>
```

views.py

```
def get_category_list(max_results=0, starts_with=''):
    cat_list = []
    if starts_with:
        cat_list = Category.objects.filter(name__istartswith=starts_with)

    if max_results > 0:
        if len(cat_list) > max_results:
            cat_list = cat_list[:max_results]

    return cat_list



def suggest_category(request):

    cat_list = []
    starts_with = ''
    if request.method == 'GET':
        starts_with = request.GET['suggestion']

    cat_list = get_category_list(8, starts_with)

    return render(request, 'rango/cats.html', {'cat_list': cat_list})
```

cats.html

```
{% if cats %}
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        {% for c in cats %}
            {% if c == act_act %} <li class="active"> {% else %} <li>{% endif %}
                <a href="{% url 'category' c.slug %}">{{ c.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
{% else %}
        <li><strong>There are no category present.</strong></li>
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

js/rango-ajax.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#likes').click(function(){
        var catid;
        catid = $(this).attr("data-catid");
        $.get('/rango/like_category/', {category_id: catid}, function(data){
            $('#like_count').html(data);
            $('#likes').hide();
        });
    });

    $('#suggestion').keyup(function(){
        var query;
        query = $(this).val();
        $.get('/rango/suggest_category/', {suggestion: query}, function(data){
            $('#cats').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

So could anyone give me a hand? thank you so much!

Comment: Do you have any error showing up? Does the message `There are no category present.` show up?

Comment: @amirouche YES!!!!!!!! Every time i input python or django, it just show up 'There are no category present'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a typo, this is the first thing to check when coding and specifically with django templates because unbound variables don't raise an error.

`cats.html`

```
{% if cats %}
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        {% for c in cats %}
            {% if c == act_act %} <li class="active"> {% else %} <li>{% endif %}
                <a href="{% url 'category' c.slug %}">{{ c.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
{% else %}
        <li><strong>There are no category present.</strong></li>
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

`cats` should be `cat_list`. There is not `act_act` variable passed to the template.

Also I recommend you avoid small variable names. Instead of `cats` use `categories` instead of `act_act` use `active` or better `active_category`. Instead of `c` which is not readable, use `category`. This makes the code more readable not only because the names are longer but because you don't require the cognitive load to *translate terse/cryptic words* to english.

I use plural names even with english words that pluralize with only an `s`. This might sound prone to errors and typos but actually it's ok, e.g. given the variable `token` (and not `tok`), I'll name `tokens` a `list` or `set` of `token`.

Comment: So which one cats should be replaced? cat_list or categories?

Comment: For a start you should replace `cats` with `cat_list` and add `act_act` to the template bindings in `render(request, 'rango/cats.html', {'cat_list': cat_list})` call in `view.py`

Comment: thank you bro!!!! I replace cats with cat_list and everything goes right. Thank you for your awesome patience!!

Comment: @曾锐鸿 can you mark my answer as correct if it's ok? please :)

Comment: But it seems that now i have not enough reputation to show the votes.

Comment: You must use the "green check mark" to mark a answer as the correct answer.